# Create a CodePipeline with a template file in S3 Bucket via CDK

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cdk

What I want is to synth my AWS CloudFormation Stacks in a gitlab-ci Pipeline. Then use the created yml file in a CodePipeline to deploy the stacks.
This enables me and my developers to check in Gitlab if the code has any errors in it, then use the cheaper CodePipeline to actually do the long working process.

In my `gitlab-ci`

```
cdk synth > template.yml
aws s3 cp template.yml s3://testbucket/project
```

My pipeline Stack:

```
from aws_cdk import Stack
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import pipelines as pipelines
from aws_cdk import aws_codepipeline as codepipeline
from aws_cdk import aws_s3 as s3

class CodePipelineStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
        self.rcs_cdk_pipeline = codepipeline.Pipeline(
            self,
            "rcs-cdk-code-pipeline"
        )
        self.stage_source = self.rcs_cdk_pipeline.add_stage(stage_name="Source")
        self.stage_source.add_action(
            codepipeline_actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction(
                action_name="rcs-deploy-stacks",
                stack_name="RcsRootStack",
                admin_permissions=True,
                template_path=??? # Here should be the s3 address
            )
        )
```

As far as I understand, the `template_path` should be an `ArtifactPath`. Which must be a CodeArtifact of sorts.
Probably a solution would be, to just take the whole Repository from Gitlab and use it as a CodeSource but I think there should be a simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: Use CDK Pipelines (the `pipelines` module), it is meant exactly for this. Not need for gitlab CI.

Comment: I found this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.pipelines/README.html#s3 but do I have to create a zip from the whole repository to synth it?

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that gitlab is not supported natively. Not sure what hacks are required to integrate it. Yeah, you can probably have your gitlab CI upload the repo to S3 and then use that as a source for the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with an accompanying Stage definition for this.

```
from aws_cdk import CfnOutput, NestedStack, Stack, Stage
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import pipelines
from aws_cdk import aws_s3 as s3


class RcsCodePipelineStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
        self.stage_source_bucket = s3.Bucket.from_bucket_name(
            self,
            "pipeline-bucket",
            bucket_name="somename"
        )
        self.stage_source = pipelines.CodePipelineSource.s3(self.stage_source_bucket, "somedironbucket/repo.zip")
        self.pipeline = pipelines.CodePipeline(self, "deploy-pipeline",
            synth=pipelines.ShellStep("deploy-pipeline-synth",
                input=self.stage_source,
                commands=[
                    "pip install -r requirements.txt", 
                    "npm install -g aws-cdk", 
                    "cdk synth --context PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)"
                ]
            )
        )
```